# How do you establish an area in which to search (restaurants, for example) for Maps.app

Tags: macos, search, maps

How do you constrain a search in Maps.app that could have hits anywhere? Like 'burger restaurant'?

I live in Chapel Hill, and I want to see all burger joints in the Triangle, so I size my Maps window to enclose Chapel Hill, Durham, and Raleigh. Then in the search box I type 'burger restaurants'. The display drops red pins around Chapel Hill, a few around Durham, and none at all around Raleigh. To see Raleigh burgers, I have to jigger the display around so Raleigh is more centered, and Chapel Hill and Durham are out of view.

Google Maps simply assumes you're interested in all locations viewable within the current window. It's such a natural way I assumed Apple would do the same thing, but apparently not.

Comment: This is so maddening. It assumes nearby is always relative to my current location. It makes thing’s exceedingly difficult to scout ahead for tomorrow’s excursions into unknown territory and plan a trip. I agree Google maps taking the current viewfinder as the filter of interest for the starting point of the results is absolutely of great utility. Come on Apple think a bit into the future, people will soon be other places than where they currently stand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s simply a limitation of Apple Maps.

To find places around a certain area, Apple touts the “Nearby” feature supposedly which allows you to find points if interest nearby your current location.  If I search “pizza near research triangle  park, nc” it gave me pizza places near the closest city center to me - downtown Fort Lauderdale, FL.

I tend to use Bing Maps as my preferred tool followed by Google. I did the same search  in Bing and the search area was as you described - bounded by the visible area in the window. If I zoomed or panned the map, the results  adjusted accordingly.

I have found that 3rd party apps “force” Google maps regardless of what you want as your default - I suspect it’s to ensure a consistent and rich user experience.

While I’d love to recommend the native tool, I can’t.  I'd use the tool that meets your needs.